# Wine or VirtualBox for Windows proprietary software installation?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, emulation

I just bought a Windows proprietary software which appears to store license keys in their internet database right after installation. After purchasing, I was provided with 1 license key, and it is said you have to pay some extra cash if you want to install the software on the same computer but for a different person. My guess is that upon registration, their database will get information on my username, OS and such. I am aware this is what I get for dealing with closed-source software, however I would like to get the best advises on how to takle this issue. Indeed, I am reluctant to install the software right now as I am concerned about any eventual reformatting, OS-reinstalling and such dilemna that could potentially render this software unrecognized and unusable if machine specifications change (the software needs to be connected to the internet).

I am presently running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (Trusty Tahr). My first idea was to emulate the software using Wine. The installation setup runs fine, but I wonder if any problem could occur later with Wine for running the program.

Hence my second idea: maybe I should just install it on  Windows virtual machine. But I am always playing around with creating and deleting my virtual machines. Which means the virtual machine on which the software would be installed could be lost. In that case, is it possible to just copy the windows virtual machine located in `/home/VirtulBox_VMs/Windows1`? If I do so and restore it later, would the software installed on it be still usable?

I will consider any advise.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use virtual machine.

First, you get full Windows installation so you don't have to worry about compatibility issues.

Second, you can backup you machine by just copying .vdi ot .vmdk or whatever format you'll use.

Third, you can export your virtual machine and even upload to some cloud platforms like AWS and your machine won't be lost ever (but it requires additional payment).

You just have to configure it right, enable hardware acceleration (if your CPU supports it), configure bridged connection to have internet connection, etc. and it'll work as fine as real machine.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the installed windows and keep it safe somewhere as the size of exported machine is too small as compare to original,

Even once you had installed windows yuo can take snapshot also of it and store it with snapshot